# Vilna Gaon, Gog and Magog war and Hoshana Rabba

Tags: sources-mekorot, army-military-war, shmita, vilna-gaon, hoshana-rabbah

1) I read on [*Soul Mazal*](http://soulmazal.blogspot.com/2012/10/shem-rashi-and-end.html), the following:

> *"...The Vilna Gaon on the Mechilta (Shmos 14:20) says that the Gog U'Magog war shall begin three hours before "Hanetz Hachama" (crack of dawn) on Hoshana Rabba, and shall last three hours only.*

Where in the Mechilta does the Vilna Gaon say this?

2) I read on [*mpaths*](http://www.mpaths.com/2010/12/what-might-happen-now.html) the following:

> *It is also a verifiable prediction that according to Rav Yitzchak Kaduri's (zt”l) quotation of the Vilna Gaon that the final battle of Gog and Magog would begin on Hoshanah Rabba, the 7th day of Sukkot, in the first year of a Shmittah (Sabbatical) cycle.*

Where did the Vilna Gaon say this?

3) I read an article called [*A Jewish Perspective of the War of Gog and Magog*](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:rqOQwmBOFg8J:www.beitmashiach.com/yahoo_site_admin/assets/docs/Gog_and_Magog.294152703.pdf%20&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us), which said the following:

> Gog (12) and Magog (58) have a gematria (numeric value) of seventy which corresponds to the 70 nations [*Midrash Tanchuma, Korach* 12](http://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma.1.38.24/he/Korach_Tanchuma?qh=%D7%92%D7%95%D7%92%2B%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%95%D7%92%2B%D7%91%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90&lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all). This seems to imply that Gog will rule over 70 nations, and all of them will join together against Israel (see [*Tehillim* 118:110](http://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.118.10?lang=en&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) and [*Zecharyah* 14:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Zechariah.14.2?lang=en&layout=block&sidebarLang=all)).

Then the article continues:

> "*On this great day [of redemption], however, they will be saved from all of their enemies for all times = therefore, it will be called **Hoshana Rabba, the great salvation...*** *The **Tur Arizal** says, "On Hoshanah Rabbah, the war of Gog and Magog will begin."* (Paraphrased)

Does anyone where the source for this can be found?

Where does the Tur Arizal say this?

Comment: I don't know, but Israel National News is not known for its accuracy or precision.

Comment: The Tur (Orach Chaim 490) writes in the name of Rav Hai Gaon that the war will break out on Sukkos. See, however, Malbim to Ezek. 39:8 who writes that the timing of that war was never revealed to any prophet.

Comment: There are 3 parts to the war of Gog miGog. This is based upon Midrash Tehillim. The first part coincides with the Holocaust and the detonation of the nuclear weapons over Hiroshima and Nagasaki. This is alluded to in Tikkuninim Chadashim of Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato. It is also following the schedule of the redemption as outlined in Sefer Avkat Rochel of Rabbeinu Makir ben Abba Mori. The 2nd stage corresponds to Operation Desert Storm/Desert Shield. The 3rd and final stage called Operation Iraqi Freedom and the War in Afghanistan is what was mentioned by Rav Kaduri.

Comment: Quite a lot of this type of information from the Vilna Gaon is the oral tradition from his students. A recent example is seen from this link.  http://lazerbrody.typepad.com/lazer_beams/2014/03/rabbi-moshe-sternbuch.html

Comment: How is the gematria of "magog" 58?

Comment: @Nic “... and Magog” = ומגוג (not clear in OP) = 58

Answer (score 4):

The writing from the Vilna Gaon are most likely referring to the sealed letter which the Gaon wanted opened 100 years after his passing. It can be found in the Rav Menachem Kasher edition of Sefer Kol HaTor entitled "HaTekufah HaGadolah". It was published in 1972 and is still available in print. This schedule is also discussed in Sefer Kol HaTor.
The Arutz Sheva article in question was actually quoting Rav Yitzchok Kaduri, zt"l, who said what you have mentioned. Rav Kaduri said the 3rd and final stage of the war of Gog u'Magog began on October 7th,  Hoshana Rabba of the year 2001 with commencement of the bombing of the Taliban in Afghanistan.
The link is:
http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/91417

The information is accurate and correct. This would also follow the tradition from the [Tur, Orach Chaim 490](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.490.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) said in the name of Hai Gaon which says:

> והכי אמר רב האי שמעתי מפי חכמים כי תחיית המתים עתידה להיות בניסן ונצחת גוג ומגוג בתשרי

This view was not only held by Rav Kaduri. For those who remember, the nascent Sanhedrin produced a scroll that was to be delivered to then President George Bush warning him that he was the one foretold in the Prophets in the Tanach as being Gog mi'Gog. This scroll warned clearly that Bush needed to support Israel or G-d would deal with him severely. The following links relate to this subject:

http://www.templeinstitute.org/megillat-bush.htm

http://www.templeinstitute.org/images/megillat-bush-2s.jpg

http://www.templeinstitute.org/images/megillat-bush-3s.jpg

http://www.templeinstitute.org/images/megillat-bush-4s.jpg

http://www.templeinstitute.org/images/verses1s.jpg

http://www.templeinstitute.org/images/verses2s.jpg

http://www.templeinstitute.org/images/verses3s.jpg

http://www.templeinstitute.org/images/verses4s.jpg

http://www.templeinstitute.org/images/verses5s.jpg

http://www.templeinstitute.org/images/rav-steinsaltz-1.jpg

http://www.templeinstitute.org/images/rav-steinsaltz-2.jpg

http://www.templeinstitute.org/images/rav-steinsaltz-3.jpg

Yes, that is Rav Adin Even Yisroel Steinsaltz acting as Nasi of the Nascent Sanhedrin reading and signing the Megillat Bush/The Gog u'Magog Scroll.

I have been looking through the Vilna Gaon's commentary on the Mechilta and have found nothing that explicitly states what is being asked. The commentary is called "Biyurim v'Haga'ot HaGra". I also checked his commentary "Kol Eliyahu" on Tanach. It is possible there is some larger, more comprehensive commentary.

What I have found is only an explanation of what the Mechilta itself says. Namely that the final redemption will parallel the redemption from Egypt. In this particular case, the splitting of the Red Sea and all the details of this are associated with the final stage of the conflict in the War of Gog miGog. This is explicitly associated with chapter 60 of Isaiah at the beginning. It also relates this to what happened with the judgement of Sodom and Gemorrah.

A little later in the Mechilta it mentions the view of Rabbi Eliezer who says that although the exodus from Egypt was in the month of Nisan, for various reasons, the final redemption will be in Tishrei. The Gra there doesn't say how he holds. He just explains Rabbi Eliezer's reasoning.

The judgement of the nations is sealed and execution begins from Hoshannah Rabbah. That is the explicit teaching of Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai as found in the Zohar on parshat Tzav.

So in context, if this judgement with Gog u'Magog parallels the timing of the splitting of the Red Sea, it would seem to be shortly before daybreak.

Looking simply at the timing, the beginning of the bombing in Afghanistan in the 2nd Gulf War started the night of Hoshannah Rabbah. That complies with the plain meaning from the Mechilta as understood by the Vilna Gaon.

This is also the explanation of how the final redemption unfolds as discussed in Sefer Avkat Rochel of Rabbi Makir ben Abba Mari, volume 1, Wars of King Moshiach, 8th sign. This is also brought in Targum Yonatan ben Uziel on Devarim 34:3.

Comment: Why would Bush be Gog? Just because Gog sounds like George?

Comment: @Yaacov Deane: Can you show me where in Sefer Kol HaTor the schedule is located?

Comment: Where is this letter located? If it is in Kol Hator, it is known that the sefer is not trustworthy.

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom, Don't forget the "Sanhedrin" which he is referring to. I don't know anyone who held it to be authentic or in any way appropriate without semichat Moshe Rabbeinu.

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom No, it is not simply because the name is similar. Although there were many Rabbe'im at the time who made a point of emphasizing that the Temani pronunciation of the soft "Gimmel" is the same sound as "George" is pronounced in English. There was also an emphasis that the specific text in some versions is "Gog miGog", not Gog u'Magog". In the Hebrew, that would mean it was referring to lineage literally, "George from George".

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt: You need to brush up on your recent history. This is a quote from Wikipedia, "The 'Sanhedrin' itself claims that the current attempt is very different than the previous attempt and that leading sages like Rabbi Yosef Sholom Eliashiv, Rabbi Ovadia Yosef, Rabbi Zalman Nechemia Goldberg and Rabbi Moshe Halberstam, who died in May 2006, have expressed support for, and consented to, the renewal of Semicha." This link is worth reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_attempt_to_revive_the_Sanhedrin

Comment: Yaacov, the source for that paragraph is the Sanhedrin's own website. I'll ask my rav and gabbai over Shabbat for their opinions b"n.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt: Another detailed accounting of the Sanhedrin formation can be found at the following link. It should be read for a complete picture.   http://www.thesanhedrin.org/en/index.php?title=The_Nascent_Sanhedrin

Comment: Yaacov, this still is a source derived from them, which will be inherently biased in their favour. I'm currently a university student, so I am viewing the lack of corroborating sources for their claims as highly problematic. If they brought a source in earlier rabbinic literature saying something along the lines of "In the year 5764, you shall take from among the zekeinim and the chachamim of your people, and re-constitute the Sanhedrin, which had ceased to exist nearly 2000 years prior when the chain of semicha was broken" I'd find it somewhat more believable.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah: The following citations are for the page folios in this translation. P45 note 131, P50 note 153, P74, P91. They will get you started. Bli neder, I'll try to retrieve additional sources after Shabbat. Here's the link for English translation of Kol HaTor: http://www.israel613.com/books/KOL_HATOR.pdf

Comment: @Noach mi Frankfurt: The reinstitution of semicha and some kind of Sanhedrin follows the nusach of the Amidah prayer. After the "ingathering of the exiles" blessing. The blessing of "Return our judges like the first and our advisors like in the beginning" is the source. That is according to Ezra and Nechemiah and the Anshei Knesset HaGadolah. This is also how the Ari z"l teaches the meaning of the prayer as explained the Rabbi Shalom Dovber, the 5th Lubavitcher Rebbe. And he is explaining the teaching from the Alter Rebbe.

Comment: Yaacov, we pray for that, but it is not ours to rebuild the Sanhedrin. Chazal are long gone, as is the chain of semicha from Moshe Rabbeinu. Without the latter, how can we hope to rebuild the Sanhedrin? R' Yusuf Kafiḥ זצ”ל held (per the Wiki link you gave me) that even if we disregard the prerequisite for true semicha, all of gedolei Yisrael must agree to its formation, something which has certainly not happened. Furthermore, you quote the Ari and Rabbanei Chabad to me; my ancestors and their rabbanim DID NOT hold by them, nor should any Yekke claim otherwise.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt: Rav Kapach was an expert on Rambam. I can't say how he poskined regarding reinstitution semicha. But Rav Yosef Sholom Eliashiv. Rav Ovadia Yosef and Rav Modechai Eliyahu worked with him and they don't seem to have difficulty with the subject. Rambam clearly holds that you don't need Moshe Rabbeinu or the previous generations. If you have a specific minhag from your family concerning the Ari z"l, stick with it. But many "Yekke's", meaning Jews from Germany do in fact hold according to the teachings of the Ari. One of them is Rabbi Yakov Emden author of Siddur Ya'abetz.

Comment: The Ya'avetz held by Minhag Hamburg, which is more similar to Minhag Polin (it was called Minhag Ostreich, for Österreich, or Austria). Maranan Rabbanei Frankfurt very openly opposed the teachings of the Ari and my screen name effectively says where my yichus originates. Kehillot Shu"m did not hold by the Ari either.

Comment: well, this was fascinating to read. Thank you!