# The reason Sukkos is connected to Gog U'Magog

Tags: messiah, sukkot, ymoth-hamoshiach, gog, umagog

In sefer [Or Shiva't HaYamim](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/622925/p/17/t/0.94964949104612131234/fs/9mzhY9Je6SvKsYy2hUbPtabfLKFSpIJQJ7UhC2YQuhE1/start/2940/end/2946/c), Rabbi Eliezer Zev Raz writes that the war of Gog U'Magog will be fought on Hoshana Rabbah, e.g. on Sukkos and Moshiach ben David will fight the war, prevail and defeat the enemies.

> מלחמת גוג ומגוג תהא באותו יום של הושענא רבה ואז יתגבר מלך המשיח שהוא דוד בעצמו וילחום מלחמתנו וינצח את אויבינו לזאת אשר מלחמה ראשונה שלחם דוד המלך ע ה עם גלית הפלשתי היה אז ראשית גבורתו הכנה על סוף כל המלחמות שתהיה בזמן משיח צדקנו

There are several questions here on Mi Yodeya, for example [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64265/27180) and [my own answer here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/137654/27180). However, I have not seen any credible sources that explain: **the sources that explain why especially Sukkos will be the day Gog U'Magog will be on (both in Tanach and other sources)**.

There's a wonderful sefer called [Avkas Rochel](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21524&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=) (thanks to YaacovDeane for bringing this), but also there I haven't seen a credible explanation on why this is. The Vilna Gaon in [Even Shleima (perek 11)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14216&st=&pgnum=105) also brings this idea.

In my answer mentioned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/137654/27180) I cited the Shulchan Aruch HaRav from the Alter Rebbe on why Sukkos is connected to the haftarah of Zecharya 14, but that does not answer the question why that is.

Please use credible sources :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer (to get the flow going) is given by the Lubavitcher Rebbe in Toras Menachem Hisvaaaduyos Volume 38 p. 53 [(שיחת שבת חול-המועד סוכות ה'תשכ"ד)](https://www.lahak.org/templates/lahak/article_cdo/aid/4298736/jewish/-.htm).

The Gemara teaches (Sukkah 55b and Rashi, sv.שבעים פרים) us that the seventy bulls that are being sacrificed on Sukkos, represent the "seventy nations".

> Rabbi Elazar said: These seventy bulls that are sacrificed as additional offerings over the course of the seven days of Sukkot, to what do they correspond? They correspond to the seventy nations of the world, and are brought to atone for their sins and to hasten world peace. Why is a single bull sacrificed on the Eighth Day of Assembly? It corresponds to the singular nation, Israel.

The Rebbe starts with citing the Arizal[1](https://www.lahak.org/templates/lahak/article_cdo/aid/4298736/jewish/-.htm) in saying:

> "גוג ומגוג עולה שבעים, כנגד שבעים אומות, כי אז ימלוך גוג על שבעים אומות, וכולם יבואו יחד על ישראל".
> Gog UMagog will rise up the seventy nations, he will reign over them, and together, they will come up against Yisroel.
>
> [1](https://www.lahak.org/templates/lahak/article_cdo/aid/4298736/jewish/-.htm) פע"ח שער הלולב פ"ה. סה"ל יחזקאל לח

The Rebbe explains that because of the holy days of Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur, during Sukkos, a person is infused with the power to battle against Gog UMagog (Yetzer Hara?). He quotes the posuk in Yeshayahu 1:6:

> מכף רגל ועד ראש אין בו מתום - From the sole of the foot even to the head there is no soundness in it (לשון תמימות שלם מאין מכאוב - a language of complete wholeness, without pain, Rashi sv. מתום).

The Rebbe says:

> והרי ענין זה נאמר לגבי כאו"א מישראל: אפילו מי שהוא בבחי' "ערבה", שאין בו לא טעם ולא ריח, והיינו, שגם לאחר שעברו ראש-השנה, עשרת ימי תשובה, יום-הכפורים וד' ימים שבין יוהכ"פ לסוכות, עדיין נשאר בבחי' "ערבה", שאין בו לא תורה ולא מצוות, "מכף רגל ועד ראש אין בו מתום", וכל ה"שבעים אומות" הם אצלו בתוקף – גם עליו נאמר "אדמה לעליון", שלמעלה מהשתלשלות.

I believe the Rebbe is saying that if we heeded G-ds word throughout the galus, we have spiritual armor to win the final, spiritual battle between us and Gog UMagog.

> וזהו הטעם שהודיעו לנו אודות מלחמת גוג ומגוג, שתהי' עם כל האומות יחד, ושאר פרטי עניני המלחמה כו' – כדי שנדע מהי העבודה המוטלת עלינו, וע"י נצחון המלחמה בעבודה הרוחנית, נפעל גם נצחון המלחמה כפשוטה, בגאולה העתידה והשלימה (ככל עניני הגאולה שתלויים "במעשינו ועבודתנו כל זמן משך הגלות"), ע"י משיח צדקנו, יבוא ויגאלנו ויוליכנו קוממיות לארצנו, בקרוב ממש, בעגלא דידן.

As the Alter Rebbe in Tanya [(Likutei Amarim, chapter 37)](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/1029047/jewish/Chapter-37.htm) teaches:

> במעשינו ועבודתנו כל זמן משך הגלות - This culminating fulfillment of
> the Messianic Era and of the Resurrection of the Dead, which is the
> revelation of the light of the blessed En Sof in this material world,
> depends on our actions and service throughout the duration of the
> galut.

Comment: A different view is no the Redemption does not depend on our actions but rather on the Divine Mercy, as it says, Olam Chessed Yibbanneh, the (New) World (Olam Haba) is built on חסד which according to T. Zohar 51ab is Y YK YKW YKWK and that's also the source of singing and saying Na Nach Nachma Nachman in simple faith  by the way.

Comment: @NissimNanach how does this answer the question why sukkos is connected to gog umagog?

Comment: I'm not answering the question just commenting on the latter part a differing view